# How can I perform virus neutralization assay for influenza?

Tags: virology, vaccination, immunity, influenza

How can I perform a Virus Microneutralization assay for influenza virus using serum from mice vaccinated with this virus?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different protocols, but the canonical one is published at the WHO Influenza site:

[SEROLOGICAL DIAGNOSIS OF INFLUENZA BY MICRONEUTRALIZATION ASSAY](http://www.who.int/influenza/gisrs_laboratory/2010_12_06_serological_diagnosis_of_influenza_by_microneutralization_assay.pdf)

It gives a detailed, step by step protocol.